# How to check filesize in IE8 html4

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

I used FileReader to check input file size.

But my LOVELY client wants IE8, so i need a way how to check file size in here.

IE8 doesn't support FileReader and other stuff.

This is what i have done for html5

**input**

```
<input accept="image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg" id="user_profile_photo" name="user_profile[photo]" type="file">
```

**javasciprt**

```
$("#user_profile_photo").change(function(){
  imageIsDelete = false;
    readURL(this);
}); 

function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
      if(imageSizeValidationCheck(input.files[0].size)){
        $('#myprofile_image').attr('src', e.target.result); 
      }
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
function imageSizeValidationCheck(size){
  if(size/1024>200){
    alert("Please upload image size lower then 200KB");
    $("#user_profile_photo").replaceWith($("#user_profile_photo").clone( true ) );
    return false;
  }else{
    return true;
  }
}
```

any good solution for html4 and IE8????

Comment: Without sending it to server you can only use a fallback that utilizes flash or silverlight in background. As you mention jQuery in your tags you could check [FileReader](https://github.com/Jahdrien/FileReader), i haven't tested it so I can't guarantee that it works.

Answer (score 4):

I know I'm late to the party, but I can actually answer this!

You have three options here:

1. Use ActiveX to check the file size (depending on the users browser
   settings, this may not work, or they may be prompted to allow the
   ActiveX object to run)
2. Check the file size on the server side, then
   handle it if the file is too big
3. Limit the request size so that an error occurs if the file is too big (you will again need to handle this error)

---

**Solution 1** (this will handle both HTML5 compatible browsers and older ones):

```
// Get the file size
var size;
var maxSize = 200;

if (window.FileReader && window.File && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    // HTML5 File API Supported
    size = $('#user_profile_photo')[0].files[0].size;
}
else {
    // Need to use ActiveX to read the file size
    var myFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var filepath = $('#user_profile_photo').val();
    var thefile = myFSO.getFile(filepath);
    size = thefile.size;
}

if (size > (maxSize * 1024)) {
    alert('The selected file is bigger than the maximum allowed file size.\r\n\r\nSelected file size: ' + Math.round((size / 1024) * 100) / 100 + 'KB\r\nMax allowed file size: ' + maxSize + 'KB');
    return false;
}
```

**Solution 2**: This depends on what your server side code language is, but it will just revolve around checking the size of the HttpPostedFileBase or length of the byte array provided, then returning to the page and displaying a message to the user.

**Solution 3** - Add the following to your web.config (assuming you are using asp.net):

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="10485760" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

You will then need to have some error handling to pick up this error (again, depending on your server-side technology it might vary).

Hope this helps someone (I guess the OP isn't still stuck on this 3 years later!).